# Oracle 12c - Opening cursor with remote tables over db link

Tags: oracle, dblink

We just upgraded from 11g SE to 12c SE.   Please note, this process worked perfectly under 11g, and only started failing once under 12c.

The procedure puts together a query, and then opens up a REF Cursor to return the data.   The query has remote tables which are accessed via DB Link.   If I take that query by itself, and paste it into SQL Plus, it works fine.

But, if I run the procedure, and try to print the REF Cursor, it just hangs, forever.

What changed between 11g & 12c to make this start failing?

Comment: What is the session waiting on?  Are the waits local or on the remote database session?  My wild guess is that the query plan changed but you're not seeing the different plan when you run the SQL statement on its own.  Potentially because you're not actually running the same SQL statement, you're running a similar statement with, for example, literal values rather than bind variables.

Comment: When I look at v$session_waits, I see "SQL*Net message from dblink".    But, what is it waiting for?   The raw query runs.  It has run under 11g for 10 years with no issues.   WE upgrade to 12c, and this process stops running.   After I execute the procedure and try to print the REF Cursor, it just hangs forever......

Comment: OK.  So it sounds like the local database is waiting on network I/O.  What is the remote database session waiting on?  What is the query plan for the actual statement being executed?  What is the query plan for the statement that you are executing manually?  Are those plans actually identical?